# Stopping plot from shaking

Tags: manipulate, animation

This code:

```
f[x_, a_, b_] := a x - b x^3
Manipulate[{Plot[f[x, a, b], {x, -2, 2}], 
  n = -\[Integral]f[x, a, b] \[DifferentialD]x;
  Plot[n, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Automatic]},
       {{a, 1/2, "control parameter"}, -1, 2, 0.1},
       {{b, 1/4, "control parameter 2"}, -1, 2, 0.01}]
```

Produces this: (if one starts automatic play)

[image]

But this looks unprofessional because of annoying up-down movements.

What can be done to stop shaking?

Comment: Instead of `Automatic`, you must set an explicit `PlotRange`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. But what if I want to keep variable plot range?

Comment: You'll have to provide for a way to vary the `PlotRange` somewhere in your `Manipulate[]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `ImagePadding` as in

```
f[x_, a_, b_] := a x - b x^3
Manipulate[
 {
  Plot[f[x, a, b], {x, -2, 2}, ImagePadding -> 5],
  n = -Integrate[f[x, a, b] , x];
  Plot[n, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Automatic, ImagePadding -> 5]
  },
 {{a, 1/2, "control parameter"}, -1, 2, 0.1},
 {{b, 1/4, "control parameter 2"}, -1, 2, 0.01}
 ]
```

[image]